# jQuery Events only work when the entire DOM is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, requirejs, single-page-application

I have a set of jQuery events I want to execute when its **own** DOM objects will load, for instance:

```
 $("#div1").on('click',function(){ /* Stuff one*/ }); //#div 1 must exist
 $(".div2").on('click',function(){ /* Stuff two */}); //all objects with div 2 class must exist
```

The next code works, although the entire DOM is too big (it's a [SPA web](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application)) and it requires to wait a while:

```
$(function(){
     $("#div1").on('click',function(){ /* Stuff one*/ }); //#div 1 must exist
     $(".div2").on('click',function(){ /* Stuff two */});  //all objects with div 2 class must exist
});
```

I would want to try this code, but [the event .load() is deprecated from jQuery 1.8](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/):

```
$("#div1").on('load',function(){
  $(this).bind('click',function(){ /* Stuff one*/ }); //#div 1 must exist
}
$("#div2").on('load',function(){
  $(this).bind('click',function(){ /* Stuff two*/ }); //all objects with div 2 class must exist
}
```

Does anyone know how to provoke the same effect using a non-deprecated code, please? :)

Comment: What if you use delegation not binding? `$(document).on('click', '.div2', ...)`?

Comment: you could go old school and include the javascript after all the content right before the closing body tag, or right after the element you require to be loaded

Comment: `.ready()` is called **after** of the `.load()` event (when all images of the DOM have been fully rendered). I want to load this events as sooner as possible.

Comment: @nathanhayfield or even more "bind-as-soon-as-it's-ready" and include each bit of JavaScript immediately after the close tag of the content on which that JS depends.

Comment: @fcortes You got it the wrong way round.  The `load()` event is fired when the DOM and included elements have all loaded.  The `ready` event is fired when the DOM is loaded - just the HTML.

Comment: OK, in the case I would be wrong...How could I wait that my elements are fully loaded in the DOM when I want to bind my events without waiting the entire DOM loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always go native and insert your `script` element after each part of the DOM you want to be loaded. If the `script` element is located after your soon to be manipulated DOM then you can be sure that all the DOM until that point of the page was already built and functioning.

You can also use event delegation and attach the handlers to your document though I don't recommend it, especially if it's a reoccurring problem. Too many delegated events on your document will affect performance.

Following our conversation in the comments, your code may look similar to that:

```
<body>
    <!-- HTML to be manipulated -->
    <script>
        require(['my-script'], function(myScript) {
            myScript.init(); // initialize DOM manipulation and attach event handlers
        });
    </script>
    <!-- More HTML -->
</body>
```

my-script.js:

```
define(function(require, exports, module) {
    // Your code..
    exports.init = function() {
        // Initialize DOM
    };
    // Your code..
});
```

Comment: In my case it's totally impossible. I'm using requireJS to modulize my code, so _I mustn't_ create scripts outside of requireJS' configuration.

Comment: Can't you use `require(['script-name'], function() { ... });`?

Comment: But... How can I say to the requireJS "Jep, My Dom Elements have been loaded, you can set this events just now?"

Comment: Require your script not through requirejs configuration but manually in a `script` tag following your manipulated DOM, using the way I described in the comment above. You can be sure that the script will not even be called before your DOM is ready.

Comment: Without changing the way things gets loaded, I think you will have to use event delegation. However, you should only use that approach for the core elements of your application so that you don't end up using event delegation for everything. If you are really concerned with performance, once the document is ready, you could remove the document handlers and re-attach them to the right elements.

Comment: You can also insert the code which initializes your DOM into a function within your script file and export it, so when it is loaded it won't run by itself, but you can run it afterwards manually from within your `script` tag.

Comment: For any reason, this doesn't seems to me a very orthodox solution, but it works. Thanks!

Comment: The best solution will be to create a HTML file that is generated real fast, so you wouldn't mind waiting for when the document is ready and there won't be a problem in the first place. But sometimes you need to improvise :)